# Make answer sorting options available on deleted questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, deleted-questions, sorting

### Problem:

Cannot sort answers by activity, votes, oldest on deleted questions.

### Steps to reproduce problem:

1. Visit a [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184118/what-programming-book-would-you-not-recommend-to-developers).
2. Notice that answer sort order tabs are missing.
3. Cry in corner.
   [image]

### Workaround:

1. Post ranty message on meta
2. Visit an open SO question
3. Change answer sorting order there (preference will be saved)
4. Revisit closed question, now with sort order last selected on previous question

### Fix:

While deleted questions are not primary content on SO, there are times when it is useful to refer to them.  Unfortunately many of these questions were popular and had many answers.  Being able to sort them without visiting another question helps this process.

- Please consider re-enabling the answer sort tabs on deleted questions.

Answer (score 2):

These now always render, even on deleted questions.